# In a plot, how do I rename an axis values into a new value or string in r?

Tags: r, plot

In a plot, how do I rename an axis value into a new value or string in r?

I have this simple data.frame and plot:

```
#rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
x <- c(1,2,2.5,1.5)
y <- c(1,3,4,2.5)
mydata <- data.frame(x, y)
plot(x,y)
```

which gives the following plot

[image]

In the Y-axis, for example, how would I change the value 1 into X, value 1.5 into Y, value 2 in Z, etc..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

suppress the axis labels first (with `yaxt = "n"` for example, Read more at `?par`) and then write your own `axis` (See `?axis`)

```
x <- c(1,2,2.5,1.5)
y <- c(1,3,4,2.5)
mydata <- data.frame(x, y)
plot(x,y, yaxt = "n")
axis(side = 2, at = c(1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4), labels = c(letters[1:7]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  IT WORKS!!   I spend hours on this.  Much appreciated.